# How to make a dynamic stopwatch?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, real-time

For some experiments I need some basic timer function. I tried various methods, and neither of them are fully satisfactory. What I need is a button, that starts/stops a timer, resets timer with each restart, updates some other variables as well besides the timer and has a trigger effect when started/stopped too. It should also be customizable for having any text on the button.

Let's see how `Trigger` behaves. First, define a switch that tests whether the counter is `active` or not, a `total` time of 50, and continuous variables for the running `time` and `timeLeft`:

```
active = False;
time = 0;
total = timeLeft = 50;
```

The `Trigger` should switch `active` and update `time` and `timeLeft`:

```
Trigger[Dynamic[time, (time = #; timeLeft = total - #; 
    active = 0 < # < total) &], {0, total}]

Dynamic@Column@{time, timeLeft, active}
```

This however has the following issues:

- There seems to be no way to stop the timer other than the `Trigger`'s own pause button.
- The way `active` is set is wasteful, it is unnecessary to test for it every timestep. Sadly, no other way I could figure out how to call a function *only once* when the `Trigger` is started or stopped. I've tried to play with the start/end arguments (as in `Dynamic[var, {start, update, end}]`) with no success. Perhaps layering a button above the trigger? See next issue.
- No label can be given for the button. The option `Appearance` does not seem to have any effect here, and even if I remove all buttons via `AppearanceElements->{}`, I cannot overlay a normal button over it and wrap it in an `EventHandler` that passes events down to the trigger, as the Trigger object cannot be set to have the same `ImageSize` as the `Button`:

.

```
EventHandler[Overlay[{
   Button[Dynamic@If[active, "Stop", "Start"]],
   Trigger[
    Dynamic[time, (time = #; timeLeft = total - #) &], {0, total}, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"TriggerButton"(*,"PauseButton",
      "ResetButton"*)}]
   }],
 {"MouseClicked" :> (active = ! active)}, PassEventsDown -> True]
Dynamic@Column@{time, timeLeft, active}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried to construct my own clock function, as follows. It uses a global clock, that starts immediately when the cell is generated, thus it always runs in the background, and the actual stopwatch is created by subtracting the start time (the moment the button is pushed) from the global clock.

```
active = False;
total = 50;
start = end = time = 0;

Column@{
  Dynamic[globalTime = Clock[{0, total}]; time = globalTime - start; 
   globalTime],
  Dynamic@If[active, time, end - start],
  Dynamic@Button[If[active, "Stop", "Start"], 
    If[active, end = globalTime, start = globalTime]; 
    active = ! active]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Note that the actual dynamic value of `globalTime` (upper value) is not copied correctly via Szabolcs's otherwise magnificent [image upload palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32/89), and it shows less than *time* (lower value).)

However, It has the annoying feature that if `globalTime` does not appear on screen, no dynamic updating is done. Thus if I want to hide it, I have to wrap it into `Style[..., Opacity[0]]`. Also, `time` is constantly (and unnecessarily) updated, even if the button was not pushed.

**Question**

**Is there any reliable built-in way to provide such a functionality? How would you solve this problem?**

I am interested in any idea, as for the last 3 months, I had to construct 3 guis with three different timing functions, and there is always something new (request/issue/feature) I have to deal with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my first stab at a solution based on the idea of a closure. Maybe it has some elements that you can draw on for inspiration.

**Function to create a timer function**

```
makeTimer[] := Module[{start = AbsoluteTime[]}, Switch[#,
    "now", AbsoluteTime[] - start,
    "lap", AbsoluteTime[] - start,
    "reset", (start = AbsoluteTime[]; 0)]
   &]
```

Timers can now be created with `timer = makeTimer[]` and utilised with actions such as `timer["lap"]` to get the current lap time. Timers are quiescent unless asked to do something.

You could extend this to handle a pause function if that's required.

**Timer with buttons**

Create a timer and some buttons to access it, associate the timer with a dynamic variable `time`.

```
Grid[{{Button["Start", timer = makeTimer[]; time = 0]}, 
      {Button["Lap",   time = timer["lap"]]}, 
      {Button["Reset", time = timer["reset"]]}, 
      {Button[Dynamic[time]]}}]
```

**Schedule a task to update the timer/clock**

Create a scheduled task to run every 2 seconds to update the displayed elapsed time or clock.

```
RunScheduledTask[time = timer["now"], 2]
```

Scheduled tasks can be removed thus:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
```

Comment: My timer has to operate at a very fine resolution level. Could you please tell me something about how scheduled tasks cope with that in general? Are they fast enough to be called like a 100 times per second for updating, e.g. `RunScheduledTask[time = timer["now"], 0.01]`?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I only included scheduled tasks to demonstrate how you could get a displayed time updated without the need for an expensive timing loop and to address your comment about no updates being displayed unless it was on screen. The timer is not associated in any way with the scheduled task.  The timer does nothing unless accessed. It can be accessed by expressions such as `timer["now"]`. These have `AbsoluteTime` resolution and can be called at normal function speeds. So you can call it hundreds or thousands of time each second.

Comment: Thanks image_doctor, and sorry: I didn't want to sound discontent, just that I never used scheduled tasks before. Using the system time via `AbsoluteTime` is indeed a clever idea, though this approach has one major problem. It does not return time in the expected resolution: if I define the scheduled task to be updated at each second, it returns the following times: {1.0110578, 2.0121151, 3.0131723, 4.0142296, 5.0152868, 6.0163441}, so there is a lag.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I didn't feel you were discontent :) Sorry I was perhaps too brusque in my reply. What delay accuracy do you need? Is it vital that periods be 1 sec, for instance, to n decimal places. I'm not an expert on this but Mathematica is not designed as a real time system. It runs on top of Linux/Windows/OS X, none of these are real time operating systems and are multitasking, so the response you will get to any timing related function may well be subject  to delay/inaccuracies dependent upon what else is going on.

Comment: Ok, we have passed the necessary routines of politeness :) It is not really important to run it in exact real time (i.e. 50 sec does not really have to be exactly 50 sec), but it **is** important to divide the total time to equal piecese, so e.g. 50 into 5000 fragments of length 0.01 sec. While `Clock` (and related) seems to be good in that, it has all the issues I described in my Q.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Nice to meet you :)  To explore a bit, I  tried this. Do[Print@(AbsoluteTime[] ); Pause[1], {10}]. This seems to be accurate to about 3 decimal places, so effectively with error in the order of 100 of microseconds. I tried the same based on `makeTimer`, it seemed to reflect the same degree of accuracy. My feeling is that `makeTimer` is of the same order of accuracy as `AbsoluteTime[]` or perhaps `Pause`. Is error of the order or about  0.0003 seconds per sample period within your criteria? Maybe there are other ways of approaching interval timing in Mathematica.

Comment: Looking back I didn't make it clear that "Timer with buttons" is the effective basis for a trigger control. You can stop the timer either with the button , or via the `timer` interface. You can put whatever text you like on the buttons in the grid. And any actions you want to trigger can be linked to the buttons.

Comment: Fiddling with schedules, here is my negative example: `list = {}; start = AbsoluteTime[];
RunScheduledTask[time = AbsoluteTime[] - start; 
  AppendTo[list, time], {.1, 5}];
Differences[list]` evaluating at every .1 sec for 5 times. It returns the following successive time intervals: {0.1248002, 0.0936001, 0.0936002, 0.1248002}. Clearly, it is rather not accurate.

Comment: No quibble with that, I wasn't necessarily suggesting using schedule for precise timing, just as a solution to the issue you raised with updating display elements in the latter part of your question which avoids the need for a tight timing loop.  For short time intervals it you would want to call the timer interface directly. Something has to measure the time interval. I gave an example using `Pause`, this seems to be accurate to a few hundred microseconds (~0.0002s), I suspect that if you investigate it  `Clock[]` will have a similar degree of error/accuracy, depending on how you view it.

Comment: Out of curiosity and not because I think schedule is per se the best way to do this, I ran your schedule code locally to see what statistics it gave on a sample of a thousand tasks spaced at 0.1 seconds.

Comment: In the end I ran ten thousand tasks spaced at 0.1 seconds. The results were,  `{Mean[Differences[ts]], Variance[Differences[ts]]^(1/2)} -> {0.100517, 0.005003}`. This seems to be at the accuracy level of several hundred microseconds, which matches the results for `Pause` and probably for `Clock`. Which I suspect might be the limit of Mathematica's capabilities in this respect.

Comment: @IstvánZachar [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7064435/615464) deals with the accuracy of the windows task scheduler.  It seems to be around 20 ms.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that scheduled tasks are very reliable things compared to the method relying on `Trigger` or  `Clock` objects. Thus I ended up using your approach, and I'm quite satisfied with it! Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad  you found a workable solution to your problem. :)