# Show animation without Animate frame and controls

Tags: dynamic, animation

the title is pretty straightforward. In my application I have one-time-run animation that I'd like without the gray frame around the image that comes with the `Animate[]` primitive. Is there an elegant way to do it, or is it possible at all?

I found out I can use an animator with `AppearanceElements->None` to manipulate a `Dynamic` variable to move the animation, but:

1. The "hidden" `Animator` leaves a blank output line
2. I need to show different animations depending on user input (buttons), and I'm not able to restart the `Animator` when a different animation is selected

Currently this is the best result I have achieved (simplistic example):

```
step = 0;
cAnim[x_] := Graphics3D[Rotate[Cuboid[], x Degree, {0, 0, 1}]]
sqAnim[x_] := Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]];
anim = Dynamic[cAnim[step]];
Animator[Dynamic[step], {0, 90}, AppearanceElements -> None, 
    AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
{ Button["CUBE", anim = Dynamic[cAnim[step]]], 
    Button["SQUARE", anim = Dynamic[sqAnim[step]]]}
Dynamic[anim]
```

This way I can change between the two animations, but the `Animator` just keeps running and doesn't restart on change (and of course I have no idea how to do it).

It's highly probable I'm just overlooking a simple solution (maybe not even involving `Animate` or `Animator`), but to the best of my efforts I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Animator` has this advantage that it can run completely FronEnd side (when used with `DynamicModule` variables), the problem is that there is no api for it except of built-in animator buttons. Less efficient but a more flexible way would be to use `ScheduledTasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started. The idea is borrowed from my answer to [How to add the pause button to that dynamic stopwatch?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/how-to-add-the-pause-button-to-that-dynamic-stopwatch/39139#39139)
It uses [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html) instead of `Animator`.

```
cAnim[x_] := Graphics3D[Rotate[Cuboid[], x Degree, {0, 0, 1}]]
sqAnim[x_] := Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]];
anim = cAnim;
offset = Clock[{0, Infinity}];
{Button["CUBE", anim = cAnim; offset = Clock[{0, Infinity}]],
 Button["SQUARE", anim = sqAnim; offset = Clock[{0, Infinity}]]}
DynamicModule[{time = Clock[{0, Infinity}], stop, dt = 3},
 Dynamic[
  If[(time - offset) 90/dt < 90,
   Refresh[
    time = Clock[{0, Infinity}];
    anim[Clip[(time - offset) 90/dt, {0, 90}]]],
   anim[90]
   ]
  ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying my answer about the [timer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133191/44141), you can create your own animator.

```
Dynamic[step = Min[step + 1, 90], TrackedSymbols -> {}, UpdateInterval -> .001]
```

where [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpdateInterval.html) controls the speed.

Then using your code as is:

```
step = 0;
cAnim[x_] := Graphics3D[Rotate[Cuboid[], x Degree, {0, 0, 1}]]
sqAnim[x_] := Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], x Degree]];
anim = Dynamic[cAnim[step]];
Style[Dynamic[step = Min[step + 1, 90], TrackedSymbols -> {}, UpdateInterval -> .001], 
      0, Transparent]
{ Button["CUBE", step = 0; anim = Dynamic[cAnim[step]]], 
    Button["SQUARE", step = 0; anim = Dynamic[sqAnim[step]]]}
Dynamic[anim]
```